# How to make QML window borderless?

Tags: c++, qt, window, border, qml

This is my QML file:

```
Rectangle {
  width:640;
  height:360;

  Text {
    text:qsTr("Agritrade");
    anchors.centerIn:parent;
  }//text

  MouseArea {
    anchors.fill:parent;
    onClicked: {
      Qt.quit();
    }
  }//mouse area
}
```

I wish to make the window borderless. How to set the properties for the Rectangle above?

Comment: you can do it like in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2235360/making-a-borderless-window-with-for-qt

Comment: any solution using QML properties of Rectangle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like impossible to set properties for Rectangle tag to make a borderless frame.

The only solution below is applicable (use 'setFlags' method):

```
//qml viewer
QtQuick2ApplicationViewer viewer;
viewer.setMainQmlFile(QStringLiteral("qml/agritrade/main.qml"));
viewer.setFlags(Qt::Window|Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
viewer.showExpanded();
```