# Custom Client Side Decorations in QML

Tags: qt, qml, gnome, kde-plasma

Custom Client side decorations or frames are quite common in GTK (I believe) but not so with QML or even with QWidget. It does save a lot of space and looks better.

Following is a screenshot of Gnome Calculator.

[image: Gnome Calculator]

What I have tried so far,

1. Disable the DE provided decorations by passing Qt.CustomizeWindowHint to Window flags.
2. Implement my own decorations (reinventing wheels is painful).

Problem I am facing

1. The custom decorations do not integrate well with the DE, be it KDE or Gnome.
2. Unnecessary codes and buggy.

This is what I have tried (Not so cool)

[image: Custom implementation]

I have read this article [here](https://www.qt.io/blog/custom-window-decorations) but it doesn't address the original problem, all the DE provided decorations are gone and you are implementing custom buttons. Now only my one window will look alien in front of all the other apps. Will there be any other way to achieve the same results in better way (in Qt way)?

Comment: You could look at this aging repo https://github.com/dfct/TrueFramelessWindow

Comment: Also there's this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2235360/making-a-borderless-window-with-for-qt